# c# exportar datos de un datagridview a excel con nombres de coumnas

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema

cree una clase para exportar los archivos de un datagridview a excel
pero ya cuando lo exporto solo me aparecen los datos, quisiera que aparezcan los nombres de las columnas tambien.

este es el código usado.

```
    public void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        try
        {

            SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
            fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            fichero.FileName = "ArchivoExportado";
            if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;

                aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                hoja_trabajo =
                    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
                for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if ((grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                libros_trabajo.Close(true);
                aplicacion.Quit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al exportar la informacion debido a: " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de los datos que hay en el excel (o una foto) para poder saber la estructura que tiene y que es lo que falla de porque no te pone las columnas.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, como resolviste?

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener la cabecera de las columnas necesitas acceder a la propiedad *Name* de las columnas:

```
grd.Columns[i].Name
```

En tu código puedes inicializar las cabeceras iterando sobre las columnas:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grd.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
{
    hoja_trabajo.Cells[0, i] = grd.Columns[i].Name
}
```

No he probado el código, pero espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera, con headertext

public void GenerarExcel(DataGridView tabla)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

```
        excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

        int IndiceColumna = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns) //columnas
        {
            IndiceColumna++;

            excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] =  col.HeaderText;
        }

        int IndiceFila = 0;

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in tabla.Rows) //filas
        {
            IndiceFila++;

            IndiceColumna = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns) //columnas
            {
                IndiceColumna++;

                excel.Cells[IndiceFila +1, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
            }

        }

        excel.Visible = true;

    }
```